# How to store dataTable contents in a localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, local-storage

I want to do is to store all the data in the table to a localstorage so that if i refresh or closed the browser and reopened again the contents are still their before it was refresh or closed. And if i delete a specific row it should be deleted also in the localstorage so that it wont comeback if i refresh the page.

My problem is, it only store 1 row of the table in the localstorage the other rows is not saved.

`current output:` http://jsfiddle.net/4GP2h/57/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a rush? Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP2h/102/) :

Right now, you're setting the `"dataSet"` `localStorage` item to the last row added by the user:

```
var data = [
    $('#name').val(),
    $('#age').val(),
    $("[name='gender']:checked").val(),
    "<button class='delete'>Delete</button>"
];
oTable.row.add(data).draw();
//Assignment operator!
var dataset = JSON.stringify(data);
localStorage.setItem('dataSet', dataset);
```

Thus, only one row gets saved. Instead, you need to accommodate for *multiple* rows using a multi-dimensional array.

Outputting the data from the `"dataSet"` `localStorage` item:

```
//Use a try/catch loop to make sure that no errors come up while parsing the JSON of our localStorage
var dataSet;
try{
    dataSet = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataSet')) || [];
} catch (err) {
    dataSet = [];
}
/*
I did not add this in here, but you might want to since if our item returns an empty array, it either has an empty array in it, in which case the following code won't affect anything, or it has a localStorage item we don't want in it, in which case this will fix that.
if (!dataSet.length) localStorage.setItem('dataSet', '[]')
*/

$('#myTable').dataTable({
    "data": [],
    [...]
});

oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();
//Loop through dataSet to add _all_ of the rows.
for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    oTable.row.add(dataSet[i]).draw();
}
```

Adding data to the `"dataSet"` `localStorage` item:

```
var data = [        
    $('#name').val(),
    $('#age').val(),
    $("[name='gender']:checked").val(),
    "<button class='delete'>Delete</button>"
];
oTable.row.add(data).draw();
//Push the new data into dataSet. DO NOT assign dataSet to data.
dataSet.push(data);
//Update the localStorage item.
localStorage.setItem('dataSet', JSON.stringify(dataSet));
```

Removing data from the `"dataSet"` `localStorage` item:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
//Find the index of the row...
var index = $("tbody").children().index(row);
oTable.row(row).remove().draw();
//...and remove it from dataSet.
dataSet.splice(index, 1);
localStorage.setItem('dataSet', JSON.stringify(dataSet));
```

Comment: Sorry! I forgot about that. I updated the fiddle and my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem is that you're saving the dataset as the current row every time you hit the save button:

```
        var data = [
        $('#name').val(),
        $('#age').val(),
        $("[name='gender']:checked").val(),
            "<button class='delete'>Delete</button>"];
        oTable.row.add(data).draw();
        var dataset =JSON.stringify(data);
        localStorage.setItem('dataSet', dataset);
```

Try appending the latest row to the total dataset and saving that instead,

Answer (score 0):

I save it to localStorage like this:

```
var tableTotal = $('#orders_table').DataTable().rows().data();
var jsonTable = JSON.stringify(tableTotal);
localStorage.setItem("key", jsonTable);
```